# How to use pandas concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Hi im running a program and I am being warned that the append method for pandas is being depreciated. How would I use concatenate in the following piece of code.

```
tweets_df = tweets_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_name': tweet.user.name,
                                               'user_location': tweet.user.location,
                                               'user_description': tweet.user.description,
                                               'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                                               'date': str(tweet.created_at),
                                               'text': text,
                                               'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
                                               'source': tweet.source}))
```

Comment: `tweets = pd.concat([tweets_df, your_new_df])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tweet = pd.Series({
   'user_name': tweet.user.name,
   'user_location': tweet.user.location,
   'user_description': tweet.user.description,
   'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
   'date': str(tweet.created_at),
   'text': text,
   'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
   'source': tweet.source})
df = pd.concat([tweets_df, tweet])
```

Comment: You could cast as a Series here, might be faster to concatenate downstream (to be benchmarked)